# Polygon not rendering on OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers

I added a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gnsmq2t9/

I am new here, and new to GIS I am building an app, and I want to put a polygon around different sections that will allow the user to click and zoom into that section.

How do I get my polygon to appear?

I am not getting any console errors.

Here is my source/feature

```
    var myOtherVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
    var polyCoords = [
        ol.proj.transform([-121.901559, 37.417891], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        ol.proj.transform([-121.901139, 37.416427], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        ol.proj.transform([-121.899634, 37.416678], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        ol.proj.transform([-121.900312, 37.418398], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        ol.proj.transform([-121.901559, 37.417891], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
    ];
    var pLotSection1 = new ol.geom.Polygon([
        [
            polyCoords
        ]
    ]);
    var pLotSection1Feature = new ol.Feature({
        name: 'Parking Lot One',
        geometry: pLotSection1
    });
    myOtherVectorSource.addFeature(pLotSection1Feature);
```

Here is my layer

```
var myOtherVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: myOtherVectorSource
    });
```

And my map

```
myLayers = [myStaticImageLayer, myVectorLayer, myOtherVectorLayer];

    //set the view, center, and zoom level
    var myView = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-121.896436, 37.413208], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 19,
        enableRotation: false,
        constrainRotation: 0
    });
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'mymap',
        layers: myLayers,
        view: myView
    });
```

I have another vector/feature layer that I am plotting similarly, and that is showing up perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your polyCoords into 2 arrays when one is enough.

```
var pLotSection1 = new ol.geom.Polygon([polyCoords]);
```

then chane the default zoom view to 14 instead of 19

```
var myView = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.transform([-121.896436, 37.413208], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
  zoom: 14,
  enableRotation: false,
  constrainRotation: 0
});
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnsmq2t9/1/)